# Issue with removing records in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a list of organizations attached to the users that need to be removed and a new set added. I am using entity framework

```
var user = db.Users.Find(model.Id);    
foreach (var item in user.Organizations)
{
     user.Organizations.Remove(item);
}

var userOrgs = db.Organizations.Where(o => model.Organizations.Contains(o.ID)).ToList();
foreach (var item in userOrgs)
{
    user.Organizations.Add(item);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

I end up getting an exception {"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."} when i try to remove the second item. Is there an alternate approach?

Comment: Use `userOrgs` in foreach loop instead of `user.Organization`. I suppose that was original intention.

Comment: @icebat Corrected my question to what I meant it to be.

Comment: It's still the same. You iterate `user.Organizations` in yout first loop and modify it at the same time.

Comment: I think [AddRange and RemoveRange](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/addrange-removerange.aspx) would be better for this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use ToList in your first foreach:

```
var user = db.Users.Find(model.Id);    
foreach (var item in user.Organizations.ToList())
{
    user.Organizations.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: This code will essentially remove all user's organizations. It it's a desired behaviour, isn't it simplet to use Clear() for that?